# Angular chosen: ng-model in the add/edit mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localytics, angular-chosen

I have an `ObjectA` including a list of `ObjectB` and the relation between the two objects is `many to many`:

```
$scope.objectA = {
name: “”,
objectsB: []
}
```

At first I load all the existing `objectsB` from the `ObjectB` table. I put them into the `select options` list. Then in the add mode, from a button, I let the user add a new select then he chooses a value. If he adds multiple selects, the selected value of each one is pushed in the `$scope.objectA.objectsB`.

The problem I’m facing is in the edit mode. For example, if I want to edit an `objectA` that has 3 `objectB`, I can see 3 selects in my view but the values are not displayed (the values in the `$scope.objectA.objectsB`)

This is my HTML:

```
   <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 0px;" ng-repeat="objectB in objectA.objectsB">

                                <select chosen disable-search-threshold="1"  ng-model="objectB.id"
                                        ng-options="objectB.id as objectB.name for objectB in objectsB track by objectB.id">
                                    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                </select>

                        </div>
```

Comment: since your problem seems a little complex, it's better to provide a runnable example for others to help.

Comment: @Pengyy thank you and excuse me I can't now provide a runnable. My problem is that in the select no item is selected in the edit mode, even if there is values in `objectA.objectsB`. When I print the `objectB` I can see the whole object. But how can I get it selected in the `select chosen` ?. I wonder if you can help me please